# Do AWS PHP SDK supports Athena queries?

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-athena, aws-php-sdk

I am working on a Laravel application with AWS Athena integration. Is there any way `aws-php-sdk` (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel) can be used for querying Athena data?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can refer to [AWS PHP SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-athena-2017-05-18.html) where you will find relevant API calls for [Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Athena.AthenaClient.html) .For example if you want to run a query you can use below syntax. Refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/code-samples.html) for all Athena API calls.

```
Parameter Syntax
$result = $client->startQueryExecution([
    'ClientRequestToken' => '<string>',
    'QueryExecutionContext' => [
        'Database' => '<string>',
    ],
    'QueryString' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
    'ResultConfiguration' => [ // REQUIRED
        'EncryptionConfiguration' => [
            'EncryptionOption' => 'SSE_S3|SSE_KMS|CSE_KMS', // REQUIRED
            'KmsKey' => '<string>',
        ],
        'OutputLocation' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
    ],
]);
```